# Fragment Layout is not displaying in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabhost, fragment-tab-host, android-nested-fragment

I am trying to add `TabHost` as sub tab of `Action Bar` Tab in Android. `FragmentTabHost` added correctly and I added a Fragment on select on any tab from `TabHost` but the layout of that `Fragment` is not showing, I have only one `TextView` in the layout of `Fragment`. Can you look at please what it is the issue ?

MainFragment.java

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

    private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater layoutInflater, ViewGroup conViewGroup, Bundle bundle) {

        mTabHost = new FragmentTabHost(getActivity());
        mTabHost.setup(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager());

        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("simple").setIndicator("Info"), SubFragment.class, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("contacts").setIndicator("Notes"), SubFragment.class, null);

        return mTabHost;
    }
}
```

SubFragment.java

```
public class SubFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater layoutInflater, ViewGroup conViewGroup, Bundle bundle) {
        return layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sub_main, conViewGroup, false);
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    if(tab.getPosition() == 0)
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, new MainFragment());
    else
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, new MainSecondFragment());
}
```

fragment_sub_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Android !"
        android:gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: where you inflated layout for fragment

Comment: @rajahsekar see here return layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sub_main, conViewGroup, false);